# Getting link from lookup document library

Tags: sharepoint-online, rest, lookup-column, sharepoint-rest-api, expand

I have created a Lookup field linked to the document library which allows multiple files.

I am able to get the Title of the linked documents, but I can't find a way to get the url? How can this be done?

This is my Expand and select query `&$expand=LeftBox&$select=Title,ModelType,ModelOrder,ID,Description,LeftBox/Title`

LeftBox is the lookup field to the document library.

```
  $.ajax({  
    async: false,  
    url: "https://MySharePointSite.sharepoint.com/sites/TransformationOffice/_api/web/lists/GetByTitle('ProjectModel')/items?$orderby=ModelOrder,ModelType&$expand=LeftBox&$select=Title,ModelType,ModelOrder,ID,Description,LeftBox/Title",  
    method: "GET",
    headers: { "Accept": "application/json; odata=verbose" },
    success: function(data) {
      data.d.results.forEach(item => { 
        console.log(item);

      });
    },  
    error: function(error) {  
        console.log(JSON.stringify(error));  

    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will not be able to get the URL of lookup documents directly using only one REST Call.

You need to make the Nested REST calls in order to get the URL of lookup documents.

First, you need to get the ID of document from lookup as given below:

```
https://MySharePointSite.sharepoint.com/sites/TransformationOffice/_api/web/lists/GetByTitle('ProjectModel')/items(itemId)?$expand=LeftBox&$select=LeftBox/ID,LeftBox/Title
```

Then You need to fetch the URL of document from document library as follows(Using document ID you got from first REST call):

```
https://MySharePointSite.sharepoint.com/sites/TransformationOffice/_api/web/lists/GetByTitle('LibraryName')/items(documentId)?$select=FileRef
```